# Issue with foreign keys in sql data modeler

Tags: sql, entity-framework, data-modeling

For my university assignment, I've been tasked with manually creating a logical model in SQL Data Modeler, which is to be converted into a database. However, I'm having a problem with the foreign keys, as when I convert from the conceptual model to the logical model the foreign keys are written as 'Entity_1 FK', rather than just 'FK'.

For example, if I have two entities named 'Entity_1' and 'Entity_2' each with a single attribute 'Attribute_1' and 'Attribute_2' respectively which are both primary keys, if I attach a relationship between them than the foreign key in Entity_2 will read 'Entity_1_Attribute_1' rather than just 'Attribute_1'.

I have been granted an extension because it has perplexed both my tutor and unit coordinator, and I really have nowhere else to ask. I'd really appreciate if someone could provide some insight, thanks.

Comment: Can you include some code in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the foreign key constraint, you can edit the table that contains the new foreign key column and rename that column.